# add and remove menu with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

well, i'm trying to multiple menu with just one button, but it seems that the jquery's code still error or lost something important.

here's the code :

the widget :

```
<div class="wizard">
    <div class="widget widget-tabs widget-tabs-gray">
        <!-- Widget heading -->
        <div class="widget-head">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#tab1-1" data-toggle="tab"><i></i>Data Siswa</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab2-1" data-toggle="tab"><i></i>Data Kerabat</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab3-1" data-toggle="tab"><i></i>Data Keluarga</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab5-1" data-toggle="tab"><i></i>Save</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

inside widget :

```
 <div class="row-fluid row-merge">
        <form action="student_post.php" method="post" name="noform">
        <div class="widget-body">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <?php
                    //$string1=sprintf("%04d", $id); for display to the  0001 0010 0100 etc..
                ?>
```

the column menu from widget :

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab2-1">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <div class="innerAll">  
                            <input type="radio" id="dkerabat" name="radiokerabat" class="margin0" value="1" /><label class="padleft5">Ada Kerabat</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="ekerabat" name="radiokerabat" class="margin0" checked="checked" value="0" /><label class="padleft5">Tidak Ada</label>
                            <div class="separator bottom"></div>

                            <label class="strong">Bekerja</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="kerja" id="kerja1" value="TETAP" class="margin0" disabled="disabled" /><label class="padleft5">Tetap</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="kerja" id="kerja2" value="CALON TETAP" class="margin0" disabled="disabled" /><label class="padleft5">Calon Tetap</label>
                            <br />
                            <input type="radio" name="kerja" id="kerja3" value="HONORER" class="margin0" disabled="disabled" /><label class="padleft5">Honorer</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="kerja" id="kerja4" value="KONTRAK" class="margin0" disabled="disabled" /><label class="padleft5">Kontrak</label>
                            <div class="separator bottom"></div>
```

etc

the button :

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-icon glyphicons circle_plus" href ="#"><i></i> Tambah</a>
```

now i'm using jquery like this (just an example) :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.my-form .add-box').click(function(){
    var n = $('.text-box').length + 1;
    if( 5 < n ) {
        alert('Stop it!');
        return false;
    }
    var box_html = $('<p class="text-box"><label for="box' + n + '">Box <span class="box-number">' + n + '</span></label> <input type="text" name="boxes[]" value="" id="box' + n + '" /> <a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></p>');
    box_html.hide();
    $('.my-form p.text-box:last').after(box_html);
    box_html.fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
});
```

continued :

```
$('.my-form').on('click', '.remove-box', function(){
    $(this).parent().css( 'background-color', '#FF6C6C' );
    $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $('.box-number').each(function(index){
            $(this).text( index + 1 );
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

here's the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVjY4.png

that's all. so i must use this, but it's all too long for menu and should i use $GET or else? thanks.

Comment: What's your developer tool's console output?Any Errors?

Comment: nope. i'm just using notepad++ & xampp. i'm not using any cms.

Comment: @ash_8247 meant dev tools in the browser where you open the page. Usually they are opened with a F12 press. There is a console, and whether there are any errors/messages in it?

Comment: nope, just can't add or remove it. by click the button add, those columns will be multiply itself once.

Comment: please provide either an example of running code, I mean something I can inspect myself, or more screenshots for each step (before add, after add, before delete etc.) and preferably with some markers on them for buttons, menu which are involved in the example

Comment: @kevinericson Every modern browsers comes with Developer Tools bundled with it. Hit F12 on keyboard when your page is loaded in that browser. You can see a set of new tabs at bottom (side panel or as a new window, depending on your browser). This developer tools will help you to inspect and debug your code.
** A dev tools window in Opera browser is shown here *http://postimg.org/image/hydf2zemt/* **